# A error 'dict' object is not callable is raised when I use Response.json()

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
test = on_command("test", aliases = {'/test',})
@test.handle()
async def test(bot: Bot, event: Event):
    with app.app_context(): 
        music, status = api.songs.songs_song_get(1145141919810, 'alea')
    music_json = music.json()
    msg = f'{music_json}'
    await bot.send(event, msg)
```

`And when I add the line:`music_json = music.json()`

A error that 'dict' object is not callable has been raised. I have no idea about how this problem be created and I have no idea about how to solve it. I've tried to delete the last two lines, it does not be solved. Only I delete the above line, there is no problem.

Here is the Traceback:
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 129, in _main
    return self._bootstrap(parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\nonebot\message.py", line 142, in _check_matcher
    await _run_matcher(Matcher, bot, event, state, stack, dependency_cache)
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\nonebot\message.py", line 186, in _run_matcher
    await matcher.run(bot, event, state, stack, dependency_cache)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\nonebot\internal\matcher.py", line 716, in run
    await self.simple_run(bot, event, state, stack, dependency_cache)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\nonebot\internal\matcher.py", line 688, in simple_run
    await handler(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lib\site-packages\nonebot\dependencies\__init__.py", line 108, in __call__
    return await cast(Callable[..., Awaitable[R]], self.call)(**values)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Kuro-bot\.\kuro_bot\plugins\arcfur\__init__.py", line 39, in test
    music_json = music.json()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I am searching for a way to solve this problem.

Comment: can you try `music_json = music.json` instead of `music_json = music.json()` seems `json` is a property of `music` object

Comment: @Epsi95 Thanks for your comment. I tried this and the outcome becomes {'code': =1, 'data': {}, 'msg':"Payload must be a valid json"}

Comment: remove the line where you are `str`ingifying `msg = f'{music_json}'`

Comment: @Epsi95 Thanks for your comment. I delete this line and directly print the 'music_json'. It may have the same output?

Comment: printing will not make a difference, will the code run successfully?

Comment: @Epsi95 Yes. The code runs successfully. Thanks about this. I'm trying to find how to get my expected output.

Comment: @Epsi95 I'm sorry to bother you. I directly use 'type(music_json)' after I change the line. Should it return a dist instead of a json?